# Display PHP code in browser from the same source script

Tags: php

Is there a way to display the source code of `somepage.php` when you go to `somepagesrc.php`?  IOW, is there a PHP function that will in `somepagesrc.php` output the text contents of the file (or source code) `somepage.php`?

I understand I could copy the contents of `somepage.php` into `somepage.html` but that doesn't cut it for me because I want it to be dynamic so that I don't have to copy the code over every time I make a change.

Comment: Try header content type plain/text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use `file_get_contents` along with `header('Content-type: text/plain')` - but obligatory security warning - be sure to filter the names of files so people can't include more than you intent.

E.g.:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');

print file_get_contents("somepage.php");

?>
```

Comment: Obligatory comment regarding sending the correct mime type. PHP source mime type != "text/html"

Comment: `header('Content-type: application/x-httpd-php');` or `header('Content-type: application/x-httpd-php-source');`. Preferably the latter but either is correct. There're others that are correct. For more info on mime types check out `/etc/mime.types` on a Unix machine. Make sure you call the `header` function **before any output is sent**!

Comment: yes but that causes an open-with dialog -- i want to stream it into the browser kind of like with `<pre></pre>'  i tried pre but it didn't work

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to print the contents as plain text? `print file_get_contents('file.php'); ` with appropriate headers?

Comment: That's exactly what you'd do. Call `header` to send the correct mime type then print/echo the file's contents.

Comment: i did set mime type to `application/xml` but now I get "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/jackpotsrc.php
Line Number 53, Column 51: Enter X: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="denomX" VALUE="<?php echo $denomX ?>">"

Comment: OK -- I changed the mime type to `text/css` and made sure that every HTML tag was closed and then it worked.  woohoo !!

Comment: You should use `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

or you could use `Reflection` through which you could easily get functions, variables, and even comments.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php

Answer (score 0):

Try easily to read its contents as any file using the file manipulation functions :) I don't know if that may be the solution you are searching about :$

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `highlight_file()`. It not only grabs the php source to display (like `file_get_contents()`) but nicely formats/colorizes the code for output.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php