# Send raw PHP to client?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to send PHP code to the browser?

The site currently have PHP and jQuery available.

For example:

```
<?php echo "HELLO"; ?>
```

this will show as HELLO on the client side:

```
Hello
```

I want to make it so the client/browser will receive:

```
<?php echo "HELLO"; ?>
```

---

Possible structure:

index.php (Main Page)

edit.php (A page that will show the source code of index.php including the PHP ad allows me to edit it (and will save server-side))

---

This is for a temporal on-the-site source code editing (because I cannot access cPanel in certain places).

Comment: you could google for it and find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696464/display-php-code-in-browser-from-the-same-source-script

Answer (score 6):

## edit.php

```
<?php

  $cont = file_get_contents('index.php');
  echo $cont;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like such. Whenever the interpreter sees

```
&lt;?php echo "HELLO"; ?&gt;
```

In order to get the contents from an external file you could use file_get_contents('filename.php');

or

```
 <?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('filename.php')); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP has a built in syntax highlighter which could help you when outputting the PHP code.

```
$string = '<?php echo "abc..."; ?>';
highlight_string($string);
```

Alternatively you could output a PHP file with syntax highlighting by using

```
highlight_file('index.php');
```