# Stop parsing PHP script and output the rest of it as text?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that I want to be able to display the source code for if the user specifies the `source` GET-parameter.

Note that **this differs** from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696464), where the object is to display the source of another script. I want to display the source code of the current script, but only if a condition evaluates to `true`, otherwise the script should execute as normal.

I also **do not** want to display the condition-checking part of the script, just the actual *business part*.

```
<?php
    if( isset($_GET['source']) )
        // Stop executing and display rest of script as text

    // The rest of the script, for example:
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = $a + $b;
```

So, if the user visits http://example.com/myscript.php?source=true he would get this in his browser (as text):

```
    // The rest of the script, for example:
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = $a + $b;
```

Comment: Couple of options, http://php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php or an output buffer.

Comment: If you _really_ want to display the source, use something to rewrite the url before the file is executed (`RewriteEngine` for apache or `rewrite` for nginx).

Comment: You could configure your webserver to show the source code of the page, without php processing, if conditions (like the source=true in the querystring) have been met.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the help of the other answers, I came up with this solution, which works quite nicely and doesn't require multiple scripts, configuring `.htaccess` or anything else.

```
<?php

    if( isset($_GET['source']) ){
        $source = file_get_contents(__FILE__, true);
        highlight_string( '<?php'.mb_substr($source, mb_strrpos($source, '**Source-start**')+16) );
        exit;
    }

    // **Source-start**

    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = $a + $b;
```

which displays as

```
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = $a + $b;
```

with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php

if( isset($_GET['source']) ){
    echo file_get_contents('real_script.php');
} else {
    require_once 'real_script.php';
}
```

and `real_script.php` would contain the code to be displayed:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = $a + $b;
```

but showing server code in the client is a security risk, so I would use it with extreme caution.

Answer (score -3):

highlight_string() is one option, Here I have used 2 single quotes to put around the code. If we use `<?php` and `?>` we even get colors of the php code.

```
if(true) // Stop executing and display rest of script as text
highlight_string(
'<?php
    // The rest of the script, for example:
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = $a + $b; 
?>'  );
```